# Numpy: 3D plot of data, using colors

Tags: python, numpy, 3d, matplotlib, plot

I am collecting data from an XY stepper table. I take data at each coordinate over a range of frequencies, so that I get a Z vector of some length at each point. When the whole experiment is done, I have an xy plane at each freq step, that is the mag of the transmission. I would like to plot this data as the experiment is working, plotting the z vector addition of each new point as the stepper moves along. This is to serve as a quick and dirty sanity check while collecting data.

```
array = np.zeros((z_len, y_len, x_len), dtype=float)
#set each z vector at each point
array[:,y_i, x_i] = magnitude_data
x = np.linspace(0,x_res,xlen)
y = np.linspace(0,y_res,ylen)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
# some kind of 3d plot
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
```

I can't plot all of them at once or I couldn't see them (freq resolution is fine ). But, I could make a plot for every nth z point and show them at a skew angle. I'd use a color scheme for the values in-plane.

I'm at a loss of how to do this with numpy. I hope that I've explained this well enough...
TIA !

Comment: I think I got it figured out...but still curious if someone has any good suggestions about how to do this. I found the plot_surface method that takes 3 2D arrays as arguments.  This syntax is not easy however...